# How can I Add Redux Toolkit to Expo (sdk 50) Project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

I'm having issues understanding how to implement redux store on expo project because of how it's routing and navigation works.

I don't really know how and where to provide the store.

my project is configured to start from this file:

//Index.tsx

```
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";
import Onboarding from "./Onboarding";

export default function App() {
  return <Onboarding />;
}
```

//Layout.tsx

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function LoginLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack
      initialRouteName="home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "brown",
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="login"
        options={{
          title: "Login",
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="register"
        options={{
          title: "Login",
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

that is the beginning of the app.

based on the way expo-router works, where do I provide the store ? Since eventually, we will navigate away from this component ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a pretty general solution to create and provide the Redux store, along with any other global context providers, at or near the root of the app.

See the Expo router [root layout](https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/root-layout/) docs for specifics.

> Traditional React Native projects are structured with a single root
> component that is often defined in ./App.js or ./index.js. This
> pattern is often used to inject global providers such as Redux,
> Themes, Styles, and so on, into the app, and to delay rendering until
> assets and fonts are loaded.
>
> In Expo Router, you can use the Root Layout (app/_layout.js) to add
> providers which can be accessed by any route in the app.

In this case you could import the store and wrap the `Onboarding` component and provide the store to that sub-ReactTree.

Example:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Onboarding from "./Onboarding";
import { store } from "../path/to/store";

...

<Provider store={store}>
  <Onboarding />
</Provider>
```

Comment: So irrespective of if any kind of navigation occurs here. The store is still provided to the whole app, yea?

Comment: @user3118363 Yes, that is the gist of providing a global app state to an app.  Any descendent components further down the ReactTree can subscribe to store changes, e.g. `useSelector`, and dispatch actions to the store, e.g. `useDispatch`.

Comment: @DrewReese

btw this is wrong solution, why ? cuz only root "_layout.tsx" is root not their screens, so it should be in `_layout.tsx` not `index` cuz `index.tsx` is not entry point, `index.tsx` is first screen loaded with `_layout.tsx` as wrapper

Comment: @Engazan I don't think I made mention of any specific file names in my answer so the relevance of your comment eludes me. Solution seems to have worked for the OP and whatever layout/index/wrapper files/code they are using. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @DrewReese from `In this case ...` everything is wrong, reason ? his `App` component is in `index.tsx` file in root so it means its not `root` component when he `redirect` or `replace` route he lose ability to access storage, because he need put it inside `LoginLayout` component inside file `_layout.tsx` to avoid any problems  

more info -> https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/root-layout/

Comment: @Engazan Thanks for the feedback but you seem to be taking issue with the way the OP named/organized ***their*** files. You are pedantically nitpicking a use case with 1 specific library. My answer simply states the Redux Provider should be rendered "at or near the root of the app", nothing more. It's up to the OP, yourself, and any future readers to ensure to render it in an appropriate global "root location" for any routers/layout/etc libraries you are using. I'll read through the expo router docs to see if there's a more optimal/specialized solution.

Comment: @DrewReese btw i reacted because i had issues with your solution that cause me a lot of trobble, so i wanted just inform you that your answer is not right, and its not, if its is valid for standard apps without `expo-router` that fine, but he is using `expo-router` as you can see in import, it means that your answer should be for `expo-router` and not for other project structures

Comment: @Engazan FWIW I'm sorry you had difficulty integrating Redux into your Expo app, but I completely disagree with you that the answer I've provided is "not right". You absolutely do generally provide your Redux store to your app near the root of the app so it's globally available. This post also isn't tagged with [tag:expo-router] specifically. In any case, I've updated my answer to hopefully make the generality a bit more obvious. The onus is still on you as the developer to apply the suggested solution correctly for your specific use case.